# Left shift key triggers left alt

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

When I press the left shift key on Dell Multimedia keyboard it behaves like I have pressed the <kbd>alt</kbd> key instead.

Operating system: **Ubuntu 18.04.3**

Output from running `xev -event keyboard` :

```
Outer window is 0x3400001, inner window is 0x3400002

KeymapNotify event, serial 24, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  32  0   0   0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x4cc, subw 0x0, time 1438677, (310,475), root:(377,532),
    state 0x10, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x4cc, subw 0x0, time 1441909, (310,475), root:(377,532),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x4cc, subw 0x0, time 1441909, (310,475), root:(377,532),
    state 0x11, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe7, Meta_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x4cc, subw 0x0, time 1441941, (310,475), root:(377,532),
    state 0x19, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x4cc, subw 0x0, time 1441941, (310,475), root:(377,532),
    state 0x18, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I have tried numerous things to reset the keyboard such as:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

And resetting the keyboard configuration in **Settings** -> **Devices** -> **Keyboard**

However, nothing has cured this so far.

Comment: Looks like a hardware error. The system receives both the signals for the shift *and* the alt key. Repeatable with other keyboards?

Comment: Switching keyboards does seem to make the issue go away. I found a Dell L100 and I don't experience the issue with this one. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: What's the output of this command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: GLib-GIO-Message: 16:36:33.898: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.
@as []