# After Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04: Left Shift key not working, English keyboar layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 22.04, language-support

After the upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, the left shift key isn't shifting letter case anymore, but instead switching between input languages.

During the update, a popup window asked me for a key to switch between "native and latin input" and I thought this was referring to Pinyin/Latin input, so I set up the left shift key for that.

How can I reverse this?

I already looked in `Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts` and `Settings > Languages` to no avail.

In the Terminal, using `xev -event keyboard` shows some output when I press the the right shift key, but none for the left shift key.

Furthermore, I'm now not very sure what my actual input method is. In the Languages settings, I can select between ibus, fcitx4, and XIM, but this apparently doesn't change anything of the behavior as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable keyboard layout switching with both shift keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048831/how-can-i-disable-keyboard-layout-switching-with-both-shift-keys) I think it's basically the same problem, and the answer should apply to you too.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203128/left-shift-key-triggers-left-alt) that gave me the hint to reset the setting to its defaults via:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

Before, the value of this key was `['grp:lshift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']` and afterwards `[]`.

Comment: Please see the answer of the duplicate question, which includes another step which I think is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Without changing `/etc/default/keyboard`, the problem would probably re-occur after system boot. This is exactly my problem, but I'm just wondering, why this question didn't turned up in my research...

Comment: Can't tell. But there are a lot of similar Ask Ubuntu questions. I happened to remember that particular one.

Comment: However, an issue remains: during boot, I have to enter a password to decrypt my disk. There, the left <kbd>shift<kbd> key still doesn't work. How can I configure that environment?

Comment: That's above my head. I suggest that you ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I created [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423815/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-04-left-shift-key-not-working-in-decrypt-disk-dialog) and hope that doesn't get flagged as being too similar.